# How can I reject repeated values input in an array and prompt to re-input until unique data is input?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pseudocode

How do I enter data in an array and if a duplicate value is entered. The program rejects and the user is prompted to re-input until a different value is input.

I need this for a project and I cant use an library functions such as If array.Contains. So I need a manual method. Even if its longer.

Thank You

```
For i = 1 To 3
    Console.WriteLine("Input num")
    num(i) = Console.ReadLine()
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems one could use a nested loop, like:

```
For i = 1 To 3
    Console.WriteLine("Input num")
    num(i) = Console.ReadLine()
    If i > 1 Then
        For j = i - 1 To 1
            If num(i) = num(j) Then
                Console.WriteLine("Duplicate entered")
                i -= 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

The reason for `If i > 1 Then` is to remove a boundary condition, specifically testing `num(0)`.

Also, changing a loop variable (`i -= 1` as I have done) inside a `For` loop is not recommended. You might try a loop using `While` rather than `For` for the outer loop.